# Linq returning value from adjacent column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table in the following format:

```
Type   Date   Code
 1   01/01/13  AA
 1   01/01/13  AB
 1   01/01/13  FV
 1   02/01/13  AE
```

Using a join against another table, I can bring back the highest date by :-

```
g.Max(d => f.Field<DateTime>("End Date"))
```

which returns 02/01/13. What I would like to know is how to return "AE", ie: the value in the adjacent column.

Comment: What kind of Linq query is that?

Comment: What type of table?  Which technology are you using (ASP.NET, Winforms...)?

Comment: A datatable. I'm working on a C# winforms app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It you're using LINQ to Objects (as it appears, having fetched a `DataTable`), you can use [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) which has a [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) method:

```
var code = g.MaxBy(f => f.Field<DateTime>("End Date"))
            .Field<string>("Code");
```

(Disclaimer: I started MoreLINQ a while ago, although others are now more active than I am.)

Comment: How is this installed? Thanks.

Comment: @user1936588: You can use NuGet, or just download the code yourself and build it. It's just a library.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get this installed, but MaxBy is not coming up as an autocomplete option. I get Max and then Min. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: This is the error I get when I copy the code directly :- "'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'MaxBy' and no extension method 'MaxBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1936588: Well do you have an appropriate `using` directive? (`using MoreLinq;`)?

Comment: I didn't, but do now - and it works great! Even handles nulls. Thanks a lot.